# Python - ImportError: No module named foo.bar

Tags: python, importerror, python-import

```
>>> from foo.bar import app
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named foo.bar
```

My directory structure:

```
In /foo:
    __init__.py
    bar.py

In /foo/tests:
    __init__.py
    testing.py
```

In `/foo/tests/testing.py` I need to import app from `/foo/bar.py`. I get the `ImportError` if I run the testing.py file.

I have checked `sys.path` and the `/foo` and `/foo/tests` folders are included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If /foo is on `sys.path`, then you can import bar using `import bar`, so try changing the import line in testing.py to the following:

```
from bar import app
```

Alternatively, put the root folder on `sys.path`, which will allow you to import the module `foo` and its contents using `import foo.XXX`, `from foo import XXX`, or `from foo.XXX import YYY`.

Answer (score 1):

sys.path should contain foo's parent directory, not foo itself

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you run your tests, you could use [absolute imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/), and do:

```
from ..bar import app
```